# Easiest way to move a Linux setup to another partition?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I want to move my root filesystem to an another(bigger) partition on my hard drive. What is the most convenient way of doing that? Is the following a feasible scenario?

1- Boot via a live CD
2- Format target partition
3- cp -a all the files
4- update /boot/grub/menu.lst
5- grub-install
6- Profit?

I do not have a separate /boot partition.

Comment: Are you using LVM?

Comment: No, just plain partitions on a single SATA hard disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time, you don't need to move the installation. Just resize the partition.
http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php - this livecd is able to resize partitions.

If you *really* need to move to another partition, then rsync is your friend.
Read its manual if you need to, but my hints are to use the -a switch ('archive' like in cp command). Rsync is better than cp, because sometimes cp will fail, or you will   need to stop it etc. No need to start from scratch afterwards

```
  rsync -rvva /source/dir/  /dest/dir/
```

be sure to use slashes after the paths.

You have generally figured out most of the things you need to do. Other than these things, you will need to edit your /etc/fstab file, so that the new installation is able to mount the filesystems on the updated partition schema.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I did that type of thing (a long time ago), I setup a minimal Linux install from scratch on the new disk and made sure it booted OK and then I copied of all the important areas.

I need to move another system onto a new disk soon and I was wondering whether [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/), with dynamic partition resizing, would be the way to go.